# Pagination is not working, how to trace it properly?

Tags: permalinks, pagination, redirect

Suddenly a website of my own started to doing this: pagination links jumps homepage,

```
www.mysite.com/page/2 >>> www.mysite.com
```

Pagination generator works correct, but WP wont show,

How to solve this? What causes this?

Comment: Things don't just suddenly behave differently than they used to. Something happened. You need to work out what. Change a setting recently? Server change or update? Server crash? Software install or update-- theme, plugin, WordPress itself, PHP, something? Check your logs. Ask your host. Post [debugging information](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress)

Comment: I see, it seems there is nothing has been changed, then how to trace that error? Any idea?

Comment: If you have [debugging information](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) post it. Without more information I don't see how this is answerable.